# Early-to-mid 2000s PC game about a monster hunter with a strange staff

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Some time time ago, probably in the early- to mid-2000s, I played a demo of a video game. It was on PC, in a third-person over-the-shoulder perspective with what was probably pretty good 3D graphics at the time, but would be fairly primitive by today's standards.

The main thing I remember was that the main character had an unusual staff with a slender body but a large rounded head, almost like a musical note, with a notch in the head. The art style was fairly realistic.

I remember that the demo very quickly dropped me into a fight with some little flying imp things in a sort of ravine, and that it gave me almost no instructions on what I should be doing. I could swing the staff to attack, but that did very little damage. I think the main mechanic of the game was supposed to be summoning my own monsters to fight for me, but I could never figure out how to do that, died repeatedly, and uninstalled the game.

The imps were small humanoids with wings that hovered around shoulder-height and shot little fire bolts from range, while I was limited to melee attacks.

My memory has confused this game with The Witcher, but I'm fairly certain the main character was much more generic than Geralt of Rivia (and this predates the first Witcher game by quite a few years unless I'm very mistaken). It may have been a sequel game; I feel like it was "The Something 2".

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Could it be Elder Scrolls Morrowind? Do these ring a bell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_III:_Morrowind  and  https://youtu.be/rJyWuUBxLEk?t=1850 ??

Comment: @Rebel-Scum Funnily enough, I was thinking that this reminded me of my experience with *Elder Scrolls II*, except that was in first-person and came out a lot earlier. *Elder Scrolls III* sounds like a pretty good shout to me.

Comment: @F1Krazy I also thought about Daggerfall, but the OP said they played the demo around early-mid 2000s, so I'd bet on Morrowind.

Comment: My first thought was "Summoner", which I remember having summoning mechanics and a staff whose head has a circle with a cross in it. There was a sequel. However, both games start with you having a sword and attacking humans.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots OP stated that they played a demo, and the demo may not necessarily have been the first level of the actual game.

Comment: @F1Krazy: The demo for *Summoner* doesn't seem to feature a staff (although it looks like you have two characters whose abilities you can configure). And it looks like the PS2 demo for *Summoner 2* starts you on a ship, and there may not have been a PC release. Furthermore, I haven't found the cover with staff that I remember.

Comment: And... now that I look at it, *Summoner* didn't have that staff on the box art. I remember it fairly vividly, the staff coming from the bottom left of the cover towards the upper right, brown wood, circular top with some straps that formed sort of a cross.

Comment: Could it be [Sacrifice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrifice_(video_game)) ?

Comment: I had previously dismissed Marrowind but I don't know, it's possible. While it's mostly first-person it does sometimes flip to a 3rd person perspective, so I might just be remembering that. The only thing is I'm pretty sure the demo just dumped me right into the game world with very little explanation or fanfare, so I had the sense that it was a predefined hero character with a weird staff as his primary weapon, and my memory insists that summoning monsters was supposedly a major mechanic, that I could never work out how to do. I'm almost sure it wasn't Summoner.

Comment: What about [Trine](http://www.trinegame.com/)?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Summoning is a major mechanic in all Elder Scroll games. Also, playing with a staff is possible for Mage characters ;-)